# Is there any specific reason behind Lum's eye color being different in the Urusei Yatsura 2022 remake?

Tags: urusei-yatsura

In the 2022 remake of *Urusei Yatsura*, Lum is given red/orange eyes.

[image: Lum, Urusei Yatsura 2022 - red/orange eyes1]

In the original version of the anime/manga, she always had blue eyes.

[image: Lum, original anime version - blue eyes]

[image: Lum, original manga cover - blue eyes]

It's a well-known fact that the hair color "change" thru the original 1981 serie is indeed deliberate - Lum was always intended to have rainbow-like, multicolored hair with a subtle color-changing effect as she moved, but since it was too difficult to animate at the time she was given simpler green hair. As animation techniques improved, her hair started to feature multiple shades and a subtle color changing effect but where kept green to not confuse fans - see later episodes or the "It's a Rumic World" commemorative video. (*)

[image: Lum in the Rumic World anniversary animation]

Yet, over all the years, Lum's eyes were always blue.

So the question is simple: do we know the reason behind the change in the remake?

---

(*) at least until the remake started to reference that and gave her different hair colors in some scenes.

Comment: maybe the same reason raiha and fuutarou uesugi got different eye colours for s2 of TQQ?